# How to know whether a formula is common knowledge in Kripke structure?

Tags: logic, temporal-logic

Suppose that we have a formula *A* which is valid in all states of Kripke structure and some transition relations. Is it generally possible to derive if formula *A* is common knowledge between particular agents directly from the structure?

Comment: Welcome to CS.SE!  Can you expand the question to define what "common knowledge between particular agents" means?  Can that be formalized or defined precisely?

Comment: Hi! I think this description in [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_knowledge_%28logic%29) is explanatory: *There is common knowledge of p in a group of agents G when all the agents in G know p, they all know that they know p, they all know that they all know that they know p, and so on ad infinitum.* More precisely, *Kip* means *Agent i knows formula p*, *Ep* means *All agents know p* and common knowledge *Cp* is *E* applied on *E* applied on *E* ........ applied  on *Ep*, where *E* is applied infinite times. I only know how to see *Kip* for agent *i* in Kripke structure.

Comment: I doubt that this is what you really wanted to ask because all universally valid formulas are common knowledge. That's called the logical omniscience problem.

Comment: @D.W. the standard reference would be [_Knowledge and Common Knowledge in a Distributed Environment_, JY Halpern & Y Moses, jacm 37(3), 1990](http://www.acm.org/pubs/toc/Abstracts/0004-5411/79161.html)